# How to access ConfigurationManager during host program startup?

Tags: c#, .net-core, appsettings, configurationmanager

I'm setting up a Worker Service, and I need to pass a connection string to `UseSqlServerStorage()`.

```cs
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<WorkerService>();
        services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
            .UseSqlServerStorage("NEEDS CONNECTION STRING HERE!"));
        services.AddHangfireServer();

    })
    .UseWindowsService()
    .Build();
```

In order to do that, I need to call `ConfigurationManager.GetConnectionString()`. But how can I access `ConfigurationManager` here?

Answer (score 0):

The `ConfigureServices` method is overloaded and includes a method that takes a  `HostBuilderContext` as the first parameter.

```cs
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<WorkerService>();
        services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
            .UseSqlServerStorage(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection")));
        services.AddHangfireServer();
    })
    .UseWindowsService()
    .Build();
```